# How to create .msp files - Office 2007

Tags: conversion, microsoft-office-2007

As Office 2003, we can create .mst files. I would like to know if you guys, know how to create .msp files for Office 2007 and how should I use them.

This is to be run on Windows XP Pro and Windows 7 Pro-Ultimate (And of course, Office 2007)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will the Office Customizeation tool do the job for what you need?  [OCT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179097.aspx)

Comment: This is not the exact thing I was looking for but it guided me to the PRF files used to create custom profile for Outook 2007. Thanks for the link and the effort!

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179062.aspx